# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln(1+2^{-2^n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I solve this: Find the sum of:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+2^{-2^n})=?$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n+1}}\cdot{1\over n}=$$

Can you please give me not the solution of the problem, but just how I can begin. Thanks.

Comment: For the second $$\ln(1+x)=?$$

Comment: The second one is the alternating harmonic series. Look at the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$...

Comment: One question per post please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2^{2^0}}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2^{2^1}}\right)\left((1+\dfrac{1}{2^{2^2}}\right)\cdots\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2^{2^n}}\right)$$
use this
$$(x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2$$
then
$$\dfrac{(1-\dfrac{1}{2^{2^0}})I}{1-\dfrac{1}{2^{2^0}}}=\dfrac{1-\dfrac{1}{2^{2^{n+1}}}}{1-\dfrac{1}{2}}\to 2,n\to \infty$$

second 2

Note

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{k}=1-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2n-1}-\dfrac{1}{2n}\\
&=H_{2n}-2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)\\
&=H_{2n}-H_{n}\\
&=\ln{(2n)}+C+o(2n)-\ln{n}-C-o(n)=\ln{2},n\to \infty
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice! +1 $ \color{white}{}$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+2^{-2^n})=\ln\prod\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+2^{-2^n})=\ln2$$

Comment: Ooops, didn't see the "not the solution, but just how I can begin"...

Comment: @barak manos In my book the result is ln2

Comment: @JohnG.: Is it $2^{-2^n}$ or $2^{-2n}$?

Comment: the first variant 2 at the power of $-2^n$

Comment: @JohnG.: Your sum should start from $n=0$.

Comment: @barakmanos: If the sum starts from $n=0$ then the answer will match the one in the book.

Comment: Ok, but can you please explain me how did you that ? Is it a rule ?

Comment: @JohnG.: Have you studied infinite products?

Comment: I may say that I had some of those

Answer (score 1):

For the second one:

1) Use Maclaurin series expansion for $\log (1-x)$ or

2) write $\frac{1}{k} = \int_{0}^{1} x^{k-1} dx$, interchange the integral and infinite sum, do the algebra and get the same results ($\log 2$).